# AttributeError: 'Redis' object has no attribute 'pubsub'

Tags: python, redis, aioredis

I am starting to use aioredis and I can't manage to create a Redis pubsub object with aioredis, despite following the recipe from the documentation.

Here's my code:

```py
redis = await aioredis.create_redis(url, encoding="utf-8")
sub = redis.pubsub()
await sub.subscribe(channel)
```

I am getting the error: `AttributeError: 'Redis' object has no attribute 'pubsub'`

Output of `python3 -m pip show aioredis`:

```
Name: aioredis
Version: 1.3.1
Summary: asyncio (PEP 3156) Redis support
Home-page: https://github.com/aio-libs/aioredis
Author: Alexey Popravka
Author-email: alexey.popravka@horsedevel.com
License: MIT
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are failed to init `redis` variable

Comment: What do you mean ? `redis` is correctly a `Redis` object according to the error message.

Comment: I think `sub = redis.pubsub()` is wrong. Because Redis object does not have that method ( follow the docs)
`redis = await aioredis.create_redis(url, encoding="utf-8")
sub = await redis.subscribe(channel)`
You can follow this to fix: https://aioredis.readthedocs.io/en/v1.3.0/examples.html#pub-sub-example

Comment: Apparently, there are two documentations for the same version of the library. I was following this documentation, which is the one the repo links: https://aioredis.readthedocs.io/en/latest/
Thanks a lot for the documentation